# I try to use const useStyles in class component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, material-ui

Now, I doing a project with React Framework and Material-UI's library.

My templates from https://material-ui.com/getting-started/templates/  --> Sing In

I change component from function component to class component to use this.state. Because I want get values from keyboard. But I can't.

It's error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mXHl.jpg)

this is my code

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
   root: {
      flexGrow: 1,
   },
}));

class Signin extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
          username: "",
          password: "",
          redirectToReferrer: false,
          message: null
        }
   }
   render() {
      const { redirectToReferrer } = this.state;
      const { classes } = this.props;
      if (redirectToReferrer) return <Redirect to="/routebasic" />;
        return (
          <div className={classes.root}>
    }}
    Signin.propTypes = {
      classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    };
    export default [connect(null, { ActSignin })(Signin),makeStyles(useStyles)(Signin)];
```

When I edit export default to

```
export default makeStyles(useStyles)(Signin);
```

It's still error.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will error. There are (very hacky) ways to get hooks to work with classes, but you don't need to use a class just so that you can have state. It's **much** easier to just use a function component rather than trying to hack React.

> I change component from function component to class component to use this.state. Because I want get values from keyboard.

As an example (I'm guessing here, because I don't know the context, and I've split out the object rather than keeping it as a single value):

```
const Signin = ({ classes }) => {
   const [username, setUsername] = React.useState("kmitlclinic01");
   const [password, setPassword] = React.useState("54788");
   const [redirectToReferrer, setRedirectToReferrer] = React.useState(false);
   const [message, setMessage] = React.useState("kmitlclinic01");

   if (redirectToReferrer) return <Redirect to="/routebasic" />;
   return (
     <div className={classes.root}>
       {/* I assume some stuff goes here? */}
     </div>
   );
}

export default [connect(null, { ActSignin })(Signin),makeStyles(useStyles)(Signin)];
```